# Have Aeon ATMs in Thailand ceased accepting foreign/western ATM cards?

Tags: money, thailand, atms

I've always used Aeon ATMs in Thailand because they charge ฿70 less than every other bank for foreign card withdrawals. (฿150 compared to ฿220, the difference is more than I spend on a meal or a fancy coffee here.)

In 2022/2023 I started finding that about every second visit, their ATMs would lock up for a couple of minutes before finally returning my card and rebooting. Other times it would work fine.

A few weeks ago I came back to Nong Khai from Laos, and the Aeon ATM returned my card when I tried to withdraw money and when I went to try again a lady from the bank emerged and said "not support". After using a more expensive ATM I checked online (, ) and couldn't find anything official or in expat forums saying Aeon ATMs no longer work. I assumed she was making an assumption and/or explaining as best che could in her limited English. I also allowed that the bank's webpage might not be consistently well maintained.

Today I went to the same ATM and this time it returned my card immediately. I didn't even get to the step of attempting to withdraw. I think it was even before entering my PIN. But the screen did have a page full of information in Thai when nobody was using it:
[image: screenshot of Aeon ATM in Nong Khai when nobody is using it]

It seems like several big changes are coming in the first quarter of 2024 to the bank/ATM services Aeon is offering, but I couldn't get a great Google translation. The Aeon fees page still only mentions the old ฿150 fee. But it might still not be updated. I couldn't find anybody talking about this on expat forums.

Does anybody know? Or can anyone translate the Thai info on the screen?

---

I'm having a bit more luck translating the screenshot now. But it doesn't all add up really.

It seems to say that Aeon is phasing out ATMs in Thailand, with various dates for various parts of the country. But not yet and nothing specifically about foreigners / foreign cards...

Comment: Indeed Google translate tells me the text is "AEON announces cancellation of ATMs at AEON branches and service points from 11 February 2024 onwards" and suggests alternatives. The english version the text is available [here](https://www.aeon.co.th/aeon/services-location/?&language_id=1) once you click on Search. For withdrawals they redirect you to ATMs from Kasikom Bank, SCB Bank and Bangkok Bank. If they remove the ATMs it's quite possible they have already stopped links to other banks and/or networks.

Comment: @jcaron Is it a notice that they're completely closing down all their ATMs, or is it a list of the ones that will be closing down while the rest of the network will remain?

Comment: My understanding is that they are going to remove all of their ATMs. The list below is just a list of the 6 regions (the same as in the ATM locator) showing when they will start doing so in each.

Comment: Clearly part of the [not so] Great Reset by our buddies in Davos, BIS, and their Central Bank lackeys.   Kasikorn Bank is also requiring Android 9 or higher in 09 Feb also.  Aeon cannot remove links to other banks....otherwise their withdrawal capacity is worthless @jcaron

Answer (score 1):

Looks like AEON ATMS will be a thing of the past starting in 11 February.  Credit to [@Jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) for the English version without having to use google translate, which is available on the AEON location search website.  After searching, a popup comes up with the English image.

[image: AEON Thailand English screenshot cancellation of ATM service]

It appears as if they will start first in Outer-regions of the country (less-metropolis areas, South, North, West, East) and then finalize the ATM service terminations in Bangkok region on 13th of March, 2024.

For those people with an actual AEON card/account, you can still get the equivalent of what you would do via the ATM their App/web portal.

If you want to avoid ATM fees, Wise (formerly TransferWise) is one of the better options I've seen (fast, and consistently lowest fees...including the exchange rate). WorldRemit is another option.  But even Western Union has been offering to transfer into bank for some time account.   Cash pickup is another issue

Comment: Your answer could do without the completely irrelevant conspiracy theories.

Comment: Why is there no warning to don my tinfoil hat before reading this?